# Best practice of exception handling in libraries

Tags: java, android, exception

What is the best practice of handling exceptions in libraries.

Working on a bluetooth helper library and there are couple methods that use the startScan and stopScan methods. In all of these exceptions are high likely because bluetooth could be turned off or location etc.

The question is if and how I should add exception handling in those methods. Do I add exception handling in those methods (either try catching or over the method headers with throws) or do I just leave it as it is to let the developer deal with it?

Looking at the [android bluetooth scanner APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html) the startScan methods that I'm going to use and others have a lot of methods with unhandled methods that lead to a crash, is this the proper way?

Comment: What do you mean by "could throw exceptions"? Everything _could_ throw a ``RuntimeException``. If they are likely to occur, catch them and re-throw them as a checked Exception.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Runtime exceptions like `NullPointerException` are programmer errors and should be prevented in your code. An "expected" exceptional condition like Bluetooth unavailability should generate a checked exception at the bottom level, but get folded into normal logic flow at higher levels.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, edited my question again and it should be clearer now. If something is still unclear please let me know.